# PHP Update using variable length form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm making a function on my website where the admin can update a players baskets of that season through a simple html form, however I'm having a bit of trouble making the script efficient and effective.

To load in the data to the form I have used this php script:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db_name)
        or die ('Cannot connect to db');
        $result = $conn->query("select playerNum, playerName, baskets from dPlayers");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $dNum = $row['playerNum'];
              $dName = $row['playerName']; 
              $dBasket = $row['baskets'];
              echo '<tr>
              <th scope="row">'.$dNum.'</th>
              <td>'.$dName.'</td>
              <td>'.$dBasket.'</td>
              <td><input type="text" name="dAdd'.$dNum.'" placeholder="+ Baskets"></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="dAddId'.$dNum.'" value="'.$dNum.'"></td>
              </tr>';
        }
```

This puts each player into a table so the admin can see their number, name, and current baskets, then an input field where the additional baskets can be entered.

Once this gets submitted I can do all of the Str to Int and maths to get the new scores, but how would I update the MYSQL database without just writing in a statement for every player number?

Also just to add, the hidden input acts as a way where I can reference that row back to the specific player in my current statement attempts.

-EDIT-
Sorry, should have said, the form allows the admin to be able to update every player at once, not just one at a time.

Comment: use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but to update the database for each of the players you would just craft an `INSERT` statement passing in the updated value for the score, and using a `WHERE` clause to denote the player that you want to update. Something like `"UPDATE dPlayers SET score=" . $score . " WHERE player=" . $dNum`.

Comment: that was the plan, to put in the sql statement something along the lines of 'UPDATE dPlayers SET baskets $newbaskets WHERE playerNum == $dAddId". But that would only work for one player at a time. My form allows the admin to update upto 99 players at once

Comment: the `WHERE` clause applies to a SELECT statement as well.

Comment: Run it in a `while` loop :)

Comment: If I am understanding you, you should create a `<form>` for each player.

Comment: how would I construct the while loop for this? sorry I'm still a bit new to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of inputs and optionally set the index to the player's number instead of the hidden input:

```
<input type="text" name="dAdd[$dNum]" value="$dBasket" placeholder="+ Baskets">
```

Then loop and update:

```
foreach($_POST['dAdd'] as $number => $baskets) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE dPlayers SET baskets = ? WHERE playerNum = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $baskets, $number);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! I will give it a go and let you know how it goes

Comment: Seems to be on the right track definately. I didn't think of using the bind_param to assign the variables inside the loop. However it's not working. There are no errors so something seems to be working, but it's not actually updating the database

Comment: I've tried printing the array that you suggested creating in the single input box but it only displays one entry. My current test has 5 players though

Comment: Obviously that input goes in your loop yes?

Comment: The input line had a slight fault in it but I've sorted that out like this:

<input type="text" name="dAdd['.$dNum.']" value="'.$dBasket.'" placeholder="+ Baskets">

Comment: Ok that's all sorted! Thank you @AbraCadaver!